# Setting up BrowserSync for laravel on localhost with elixir

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, browser-sync

I'm trying to implement BrowserSync in Laravel with elixir. So the browser updates itself on every save i make in my .scss file

---

**To simulate the php server**

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t public // executed from project folder with git bash
```

**Gulp.js File**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();


elixir(function(mix) {
  mix.browserSync({
      base: './public',
      proxy: 'localhost',
      port: 8888
  });
});
```

Everything runs ok. When i use `gulp watch` the function is watching my files and notices that `styles.scss` in the folder `public/css/` updated. But my browser on `localhost:8888` is not refreshing with the new css generated from the style.scss. Can someone suggest the changes I have to make to make this thing work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change a few things:

**Simulate PHP server with following command:**

```
php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1
```

**Gulp.js**

```
elixir(function(mix) {
  mix.browserSync({proxy: 'localhost:8000'});
});
```

This code is enough to let it run. Feel free to post suggestions.

Comment: Simple and nice